# Jquery code to select radio button

Tags: jquery

i have 3 radio buttons

```
male,female ,none
```

and a json that is returned as the result of db operations

```
var mydata ={
    "_id": "524d1c36497c4d6f3c56bb84",
    "browser": "IE8",    
    "status": "male"    // May be male or female or none
}
```

Radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" id="rad3" name="case" value="male" />Male
<input type="radio" id="rad1" name="case" value="female"/>Female
<input type="radio" id="rad2" name="case" value="none"/>None
```

From the above Json data am getting the "`status" value as male` and have to automatically select `male radio button`.how it is possible.

Comment: Are you sure you can have none also, along with male and female :)

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=google+select+radio+button+jquery&oq=google+select+radio+button+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.8541j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&newwindow=1&q=select+radio+button+jquery+stackoverflow What's wrong with these results?

Comment: 3 times the same ID ???

Comment: I think you want to put < ... checked="checked" ...> inside the element you want.

Comment: +1 for the 'none' gender..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var radioButtonToCheck = $("input[value='"+mydata.status+"']");
if(radioButtonToCheck !=null){
  radioButtonToCheck.prop("checked",true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mydata.status == "male"){
    $("#rad3").prop("checked", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
$('input[value="' + mydata.status + '"]').prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write following code in ajax response:

```
if(mydata.status == "male"){
    $("#rad3").prop("checked", true);
}else if(mydata.status == "female"){
    $("#rad1").prop("checked", true);
}else{
    $("#rad2").prop("checked", true);
}
```